# Получение выбранного элемента списка python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

У меня есть список из 6 елементов. Я получаю его в виде выпадающего списка через `bootstrap-select`. Я могу получать элементы списка в консоль только если форма отправляется на обработку.
Вопрос:

**Как сделать так, чтобы при выборке элемента, я сразу могу печатать его в консоль, еще до отправки формы?**

`app.py`

```
description = ['one','two','three','four','five','six']

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        docs = request.form.getlist('sel')
        print(docs)
        return render_template('login.html', description=description)
    return render_template('login.html', description=description)
```

`login.html`

```
      <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
          {% for desc in description %}
            <option value="{{desc}}">{{desc}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Identify</button>
      </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').selectpicker();
  </script>
```

Comment: Я знаю, что означает выражение "получить в морду". А что означает "получить в консоль" ?

Comment: @Sergey, делать `print`, фактически просто выводить в консоль

Comment: "еще до отправки формы" - Вы  понимаете, что означает конструкция, которую Вы используете в программе: "@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():" ? Здесь Вы инструктируете Ваш HTTP сервер - запусти функцию *login()* прои поступлении GET или  POST запроса. Понимаете? ПОСЛЕ того, как придёт запрос, начнёт выполняться эта функция.

Comment: @Sergey, я понимаю. я получаю страницу `login`, и на ней хочу получать то что выбираю

Comment: И сервер сформирует ответ **после** того, как пользователь нажмёт кнопку *submit*. Не ранее...

Comment: @Sergey, то есть это ни как не решить?

Comment: Во всяком случае - я не знаю как такое можно сделать.

Comment: @Sergey,я думал может через JQuery как то фиксировать выбранные элемент, потом выводить его.

Comment: Что происходит на самом деле?

1) Браузер на локальном хосте отправляет GET('/') 

2) Сервер принимает, формирует HTML и отправляет обратно

3) Браузер принимает HTML, рисует её и показывает drop-box

4) Пользователь выбирает значение и нажимает submit

5) Браузер отправляет GET с заполненной формой.

6) Сервер вызывает ф-цию *login()* и передаёт ей форму.

7) Функция принимает выбор из drop-box и может его распечатать.

Comment: Короче говоря: пользователь делает выбор на локальном ХОСТЕ, а Ваша функция работает  на СЕРВЕРЕ. И что бы выбор попал на сервер нужно выполнить запрос GET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашел такое решение:

```
<select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" onchange="printValue(this)">
   {% for desc in description %}
      <option value="{{desc}}">{{desc}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
<p id="mySelectedValue" style="margin-top: 10px;"></p>



<!-- In your script, call your function, which prints the data in your console-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printValue(selectedItem){
       $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Никак. Делим проект на *Frontend* и *Backend*.
В данном случае `Flask` генерирует разметку и отправляет её клиенту. Далее на клиенте исполняется уже **JS**, НЕ **PYTHON**, КОТОРЫЙ ИСПОЛНЯЕТСЯ НА **BACKEND**.
Следовательно, выбранный параметр можно асинхронно отправлять через **JS** на непосредственно **backend**. Удобнее всего это делать через `AJAX`.
Пример:

```
$.post(
"/someadress",
{
param1: "param1",
param2: 2
},
 onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
// Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
alert(data);
}
```

Кидаете данный код в функцию, функцию в `onclick` свойство (ну или куда хотите) .
Не забудьте добавить в *HTML* референс на `Jquery`. Именно там обитает `AJAX`.
Ну и не забудьте сделать `listener` на `Flask` ->

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/someadress', methods=['POST'])
def somemethod():
   print(request.data)
   return 'ok'
```